# Why can't I open and run a .java file in Intellij, empty configuration

Tags: intellij-idea, configuration

So I was following a lecture of CS61B for an exsercie question, and I've downloaded this .java file from the class's repo, and then when I opened it in IntelliJ, it shows "Project JDK is not defined", so I clicked on it and set it as Java 17.

After that, the interface is as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eLvx.png)

when I right click on the ArraySet.java file there isn't a "run" option, it shows this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZeHk.png)

However, if I simply open a new project and copy and paste the code there, it'll work just fine. It's just that when I open the file directly, it cannot run for some reason. I'm just starting to learn java and IntelliJ, and I've looked everywhere but still am not able to solve it, if someone can help me out on this, it'll be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please create "src" folder under project root, mark it as "Sources Root" (right click -> Mark directory as) and put your class there.

Comment: But when I right click on ArraySet.java1 and create a new directory names src, it doesn't show up down there, and when I tried to create it again, it says it's alreay exists. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Please try to create new project from welcome screen and then add you code there.

Comment: This may seem like a dumb question, I apologize for that haha, is there a way to import that .java file into a new project? The only way that I found that works so far is to open a new project and then create a new class and copy and paste the code there.

Comment: You could simply copy/paste file inside your src folder.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was such a simple solution that I couldn't think of LOL

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by:

1. go to file-project settings-project, and change the SDK to 16 or whatever you have in your pc
2. Goto File->Project Structure->Modules->Choose Your Module->Make sure your folder is marked as "sources"
   After that, I can run each configuration cooresponding to the lab

Comment: Thanks for your info, I solved it by creating a src folder and copying & pasting the file inside the src folder:)